# output element from the array with different index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table. When I click on an element I return its index. How can I (starting from this element) display all elements with index + 9. i.e. if the selected element has index 0, then I also need to display elements with indexes 9, 18, 27, etc.

```
let newCell = [td#2, td#0, td#2, td#0, td#2, ..... td#1, td#0]

newCell.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {   
        console.log(i)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not included the code to "display" those elements that will come in the series, but below is the code that logs them out. You can update it to display them.

```
const DIFF = 9;

newCell.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', ()=>logAllItemsInSeries(i));
}

const logAllItemsInSeries = (i) => {
    console.log(i);
    const series = [];
    while (i < newCell.length) {
        series.push(i);
        i += DIFF;
    }
    series.forEach((index) => {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(newCell[index]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in this case is keep track of a count of what elements should be filtered out and then update that count as you filter through it. Unfortunately your cell data is unclear to me so I went ahead and made my own to explain.

```js
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push({ id: i });
}

function getByNine(id) {
    let count = id + 9
    
    return data.filter(i => {
        if (i.id === count) {
            count = count + 9
            return i
        } else {
            return
        }
    })
}

console.log(getByNine(3))
```

1. Inside your event listener you would put a reference to the `getByNine(i)` function (or whatever you want to call it) and pass its index.
2. Inside this function you set a default count of 9 + whatever the id of the element clicked
3. Run a filter through your array of objects, when the count is correct return that item and then increment the count by 9 for the next correct element

```
function getByNine(i) {
   // code here
}

newCell.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {   
        getByNine(i)
    })
})
```